# How do the various statistics affect my character?

Tags: realms-of-despair

There are 9 statistics in Realms of Despair that appear on my character's score sheet (strength, intelligence, wisdom, dexterity, charisma, constitution and luck).

How do these statistics affect my character while leveling and after I reach avatar?

Answer (score 1):

```
                 PreAv  Avatar    Effect

Strength            x      x       Affects the amount of weight that can be carried1
                    x      x       Adds to damage roll
Intelligence        x              Affects the amount of experience gained per hit
                    x      x       Affects the success of spellcasting attempts
                           x       Affects thieves' poison weapon ability
Wisdom              x              Affects mana gain per level
Dexterity           x              Affects number of practices gained per level
Charisma            x      x       One factor in purchase price of items
                    x      x       Increases gold dropped by mobiles.
Constitution        x              Critical in hit point gains per level.
                    x      x       Reduces damage taken on a sliding but unlimited scale.
Luck                x      x       Affects the hit percentage of thieves' circle attack.
```